# Is xgoogle no longer working?

Tags: python, xgoogle

I just want to confirm if xgoogle is no longer working for automated search. I followed the first example on this website http://www.catonmat.net/blog/python-library-for-google-search/.

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
try:
  gs = GoogleSearch("quick and dirty")
  gs.results_per_page = 50
  results = gs.get_results()
  for res in results:
    print res.title.encode("utf8")
    print res.desc.encode("utf8")
    print res.url.encode("utf8")
    print
except SearchError, e:
  print "Search failed: %s" % e
```

It only gave me three search results, and they are different from what I got on the browser. It's no longer working, right?

Answer (score 3):

I contacted the author of xgoogle and was told that it's no longer working.