# Install xGoogle from pip?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, xgoogle

Is there a way to install xGoogle through pip? If so, how do I do this? I have already tried:
`$ pip install xGoogle`
If there is not a way to install using pip, can I do it through easy-install?
I am using Windows 10 for my operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install it directly from its [repository](https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle) doing:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle
$ cd xgoogle
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle
$ cd xgoogle
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case linked answer did not help.

In `from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError` line, xgoogle, GoogleSearch and SearchError required `Install package xgoogle`, `Install package GoogleSearch` and `Rename reference` for `SearchError`, but Error occurred during `pip install xgoogle` command execution:

```
Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xgoogle (from versions: none)
```

**Command output:**

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xgoogle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xgoogle
```

I've downloaded [xgoogle.zip](https://catonmat.net/ftp/xgoogle.zip) from the [author's web page](https://catonmat.net/python-library-for-google-search), extracted it and placed it into my `~/PycharmProjects/myproject/` folder. And it works for this project.

But, nevertheless, xgoogle package is [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33616288/10854998) now.